# Add directive to elements produced by ng-grid

Tags: jquery, angularjs, excel, ng-grid

Using `ng-grid`, I developed a simple application to render an excel sheet in UI. I want the fields(table headers) to be draggable, so that I can drop them at run time into some bins, somewhat like - [this](http://blog.parkji.co.uk/2013/08/11/native-drag-and-drop-in-angularjs.html). The only difference being, here I will be dragging the excel column header.

I can't figure out how to add directive "draggable" to something generated by ng-grid.

P.S. Every column header has to have its own "draggable", so that I may uniquely identify the column number/name

Angular code goes like :

```
var sth = {"excelData" : [{"Name":"Rohan","Id":"1001.0","Salary":"50000.0","Age":"25.0"},{"Name":"Rohit","Id":"1002.0","Salary":"60000.0","Age":"24.0"},{"Name":"Rahul","Id":"1003.0","Salary":"55000.0","Age":"29.0"},{"Name":"okay bye","Id":"1004.0","Salary":"88214.0","Age":"32.0"}]};
        $scope.myData = sth.excelData;
        $scope.gridOptions = { data: 'myData' };
```

In my HTML, I use:

```
<div class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions">
</div>
```

Here, Name, Id, Salary, Age, all should be independently and individually draggable.

[image]

P.S. Given static json only for understanding. It gets generated at run time and may be very huge.

Comment: In the API section at http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/ there is mention of a property `headerCellTemplate` (under the headline `ColumnDefs Options`), maybe you can use that.

Comment: Could you please answer me here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30187845/default-headercell-template-in-ng-grid Thanks